# ,,Improper \halign inside $$'s`` with lmodern/microtype/fontspec

Tags: amsmath, fontspec, microtype, lmodern

This is less of an actual problem than a "why does this happen" question. When working on a larger document, I started getting spurious and (to me) inexplicable `Improper \halign inside $$'s.` errors from `amsmath`'s `align` and `align*` environments.

Bisecting to an MWE, I quickly found that I'd loaded both `fontspec` and `lmodern`, the latter likely left-over from before I switched to one of the Libertinus fonts. Not loading `lmodern` then fixed the problem, but I'm still intellectually curious as to *why* this happened.

Here is an MWE (I'm using XeTeX, in case it might make a difference):

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}           % (1)
\usepackage{fontspec}          % (2)
\usepackage{microtype}         % (3)
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif} % (4)
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        a & b
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Commenting out *any* of the lines marked (1)--(4) makes the problem disappear (if you comment out (2) you'll also have to comment out (4), of course).

I'm quite puzzled by what's going on there behind the scenes. Can anyone shed light on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: This has been fixed in `microtype` v3.0.

---

This is a bug in `microtype`:

Instead of `{` and `}` it should use `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` in the following:

```
\def\MT@set@inh@list#1#2{%
  \MT@ifempty\MT@inh@feat{%
    \MT@map@clist@c\MT@features{\begingroup % <--
      \MT@ifstreq{##1}{tr}\relax{\MT@declare@char@inh{##1}{#1}{#2}}%
    \endgroup}% <--
  }{%
    \MT@map@clist@c\MT@inh@feat{\begingroup % <--
      \KV@@sp@def\@tempa{##1}%
      \MT@ifempty\@tempa\relax{%
        \edef\@tempa{\csname MT@rbba@\@tempa\endcsname}%
        \MT@ifstreq\@tempa{tr}\relax{%
          \MT@exp@one@n\MT@declare@char@inh{\@tempa}{#1}{#2}}}%
    \endgroup}% <--
  }%      
  \MT@end@catcodes
}
```

which explains the four empty math atoms @David found. I'll change this for the next version, but for now adding the above to the preamble should fix it.

(BTW: Thanks for the perfect MWE!)

Comment: ah I guessed it was { not \begingroup but \tracingall isn't always easy to read:-) Thanks for the quick fix.

Comment: Excellent! You're very welcome, and thank you for the fix!

Answer (score 5):

You only get the error if this is the first math expression. Some of the initial setup is happening at a delicate time. You can use a simple math expression in a discarded box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}           % (1)
\usepackage{fontspec}          % (2)
\usepackage{microtype}         % (3)
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif} % (4)
\begin{document}
\sbox0{$x$}
    \begin{align}
        a & b
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see, thank you! "*Some of the initial setup is happening at a delicate time*" --- spoken like a true wizard.

Comment: @chsk  I did run tracing and something is causing four `{}` empty math atoms but I seeing exactly where is a bit tricky it's not code I know well. the multiple font declarations are making microtype do font setup at the start of the display, I think.